In data insertion of Apache IoTDB, what configuration did setting rowSize stores?
I would like to ask is it necessary to set rowSize when inserting data into Apache IoTDB using insertTablet? Without setting rowSize, the system will not throw any exception error, but there also will be no data inserted into the database. If rowSize is mandatory to set, I don't quite understand why this parameter is necessary. In my understanding, if the data comes, just insert it directly should be fine. I feel that this parameter is difficult to understand, so I also want to know what is the effect of setting rowSize?

In Apache IoTDB, since a tablet unit can be reused, after a write task is completed, the rowSize will be cleared after the same tablet is reset, but the original data value in the tablet is actually not cleared. When inserting new data, these data will repeatedly cover the corresponding position in the tablet. The rowSize here is to record the position information of the valid value, therefore for newest data reserved settings in IoTDB, this parameter is mandatory to be set.
